# SharePoint site/pages being forcibly opened in IE despite Chrome is used, and IE shows using Chrome instead

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I encountered this issue in our internal sites, a site I tried to open with **Chrome**, IE will be automatically chosen, but in IE, it shows error message below:

> This browser is not supported. Use Chrome instead

Did anyone have same experience? How do I open the site/pages?

Thank you very much, any clue is appreciated.

Comment: What steps are you performing to open the site? For example, do you already have Chrome open and you're clicking a link, which opens in IE? Are you clicking a link from within an email client?

Comment: I have the link, click on the link in Chrome, the link is opened in IE, error is from IE indicating I should open it from Chrome which I already did.

Comment: Is the link on a web page? I'd be curious to see the HTML that defines the link.

Comment: Do you click a link in a web page in Chrome and then it is opened in IE? Does the situation happen in a certain website or all the websites you visit in Chrome? For now, you could try to [set Chrome as default browser](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) or paste the link in Chrome's address bar and directly go to the link you want to open in Chrome to see if it works.